# Can't submit Tag Wiki Edits

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, editing, suggested-edits

I have a few edits to Tag Wikis queued up and I'm having trouble submitting them.  I wait the normal 30 sections between submissions, but then I get a tooltop that says "An error occurred submitting this post." and this is logged in the console:

```
http://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/edit-tag-wiki/submit/68
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
jquery.min.js:4 GET http://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/edit-tag-wiki/submit/68 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Is this due to the new restrictions on suggested edits on the Stack Exchange network?  Should I post on Meta.SE?

If this is in fact by design, then this is a Stack Exchange network issue.  I have submitted a bug report on meta [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/281952/242209).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a limit to the number of pending suggested edits that any user can have.

As in this main meta post:  [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164899/236563)  The limit is 20 on beta sites such as ours (only 5 on graduated sites).

As I write this, there are 20 suggested edits in the queue.  That is most probably the reason.

Give us a while to review them, and keep the tag wikis coming!

Comment: Got it.  So it looks like this is a Stack Exchange bug.  Submitting that 21st edit shouldn't return a server error, it should alert me that I have hit the suggested edit limit.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Chenmunka, submitted a bug report here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/281952/242209

Comment: FWIW, I highly doubt this was the 20-edit limit, Chenmunka, @JAL - that kicks in *before* you're allowed to edit, not afterwards. And from the look of things, JAL had queued up quite a few edits a half-hour before and was working through them. Chances are, *that* had more to do with the problem than anything; there's some validation that happens on form submission to discourage replay attacks, and it can get real unhappy if you're submitting a form you've had open while doing other things in other tabs.

Comment: Hi @Shog9, that makes sense.  I will avoid queueing up edits like this in the future.  Thanks!

Comment: Nothing wrong with queuing up pages to edit, @JAL, but I'd generally try to avoid loading up the actual edit forms too far ahead of time. Not only does this start to look rather bot-like, it can be a real headache if *someone else* decides to edit these in the meantime (depending on your connection and how fast you actually edit, you may or may not get notified of this). If nothing else, refresh the page before you actually start typing to make sure you've grabbed the latest version.